# React Native shadow

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im doing react-native and i have this problem,
I declare the shadow color and also elevation, but the top shadow is thinner than the bottom, i have tried shadowOffset with width: 0 and height: 0 but no use, anyone can help me ?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A65vJ.jpg)

here's my style code

```
circle: {
    marginTop: 48,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 248,
    height: 248,
    borderRadius: 248,
    backgroundColor: '#141414',
    shadowColor: '#D8D8DF',
    elevation: 24
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you out but in the past I have used....

[React Native Shadow Generator](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/)